# Jquery .closest() on Bootstrap Datepicker returning undefined

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm working with the [Bootstrap Datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/index.html) and I'm trying to close the popup I have when there's a click outside of the modal. The problem I'm having is that clicks on the table `<td>` elements don't return the parent div its in when I use `$(e.target).closest('.datepicker')`. If I click the blue box around it (also a child element) it returns the parent div but not for clicks in the table.

http://jsfiddle.net/tuG6C/662/

**JS**

```
$('body').click(function(e){
    console.log($(e.target).closest('.datepicker')[0]); 
});    

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        startDate: new Date()
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="datepicker"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.datepicker {
    padding: 20px;
    background: aliceblue !important;
    display: inline-block;
}
table {
    background: #fff;
}
```

Screencast of the problem. I'm trying to avoid the `undefined` output.

[image]

Comment: The only time I can't get the calendar to close is when I click on the input div: <div class="input-append date datepicker no-padding"></div>.  That's because the div spans the whole area.  Otherwise, the modal and the calendar close fine when clicking outside.

Comment: @deamak this is just a small example of the problem. The custom modal I have has other elements in it, i.e. its not using the calendar modal that came with this datepicker library. The problem is that I need the console to output the parent div `.datepicker` whenever I click inside the calendar.

Comment: I'm stumped.  The only thing I can think of is it has something to do with jQuery binding the td elements somehow.  An alternative might be to use native JS, as jQuery probably is and loop through e.target.parentNode until you reach the datepicker class. Something like: var getClosest = function(el, searchClass) {
    var parentNode = el;
    while(parentNode.className != searchClass) {
        parentNode = el.parentNode;
    }
    return parentNode;
}

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. After hours of frustration, figured out that it does not work because the clicked target is not where you would expect it to be (under `'.datepicker'`).

Instead, the parent of the clicked `<td>` is a `<tr>` with NO `parentNode`, which makes determining if we are in the popup very hard - one could try searching the DOM to locate the element, but I don't even know if it would be present at all.

The solution used here was a check to see if

```
$(e.target).closest('body').length == 0
```

in which case the popup is left open

See [this issue](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/issues/692)